# Value replacement without using the assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "Making A" << endl; }
    A& operator=(const A& other) = delete;
};


int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    a = A();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling gives the following error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall test.cc -o test && ./test
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:17:7: error: use of deleted function ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)’
     a = A();
       ^
test.cc:9:8: error: declared here
     A& operator=(const A& other) = delete;
        ^
```

I want to "reset" the value of `a` to a newly constructed `A`. Is there a way for me to do this by only using the constructor? That is, without using the assignment operator which needs to be deleted in my real-world code?  I tried, for instance, using `std::move` a la `a = std::move(A());`, but that gives the same error.

Comment: Can't you add `A& operator=(A&&) = default;` ?

Comment: Why do you need to delete the assignment operator? That's a pretty odd requirement.

Comment: @NirFriedman In my code `operator=` is implicitly deleted and it's not easy for me to add it.

Comment: @Jarod42 This is a minimal example.  Naturally I wouldn't delete `operator=` if I could avoid it. In my case, `operator=` is implicitly deleted by the compiler.

Comment: @firebush can you expand a little bit on why? Are you sure that it applies to `operator=(A&&)` as well as `operator=(const A&)` ?

Comment: @firebush I would love to know what in your code implicitly deletes `operator=` . I guess an inheritance from a base class that does so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only call the constructor for an object once. After that, the object is already constructed, and cannot be constructed a second time.

You can destroy the object and reconstruct it in place:

```
a.~A();
::new (&a) A();
```

If you find yourself needing to do this often, it's better to just provide a `.clear()` member or something similar... or maybe just not delete the assignment operator. You haven't provided enough detail.

Comment: This answers my question.  A clear isn't an option for me because I'm inheriting from a class defined in a third-party library and I don't have a mechanism to properly clear it. Is there more information you need?